# Connection between BQP and Feynman Path Integral

Tags: quantum-information, path-integral, quantum-computer

In chapter 10 of Scott Aaronson's book *Quantum Computing Since Democritus*, he claims that Feynman path integral formulation immediately implies that the complexity class BQP (Bounded-error Quantum Polynomial Time) is contained in PP (Probabilistic Polynomial Time). However, I don't see how the argument works.

Here is my understanding of it: any problem that can be reduced to a decision problem of **whether or not the sum of exponentially many terms (each computable in polynomial time) is above a certain threshold** is in PP. So Aaronson shows that by the Path Integral approach, all BQP computations can be reduced to such a decision problem. Great, so BQP is in PP.

But what I don't understand is why the traditional approach described by Aaronson doesn't work (see below):

"The obvious way to do it is to multiply a bunch of $2^n$ by $2^n$ unitary matrices, then take the sum of the squares of the absolute values of the amplitudes corresponding to accepting basis states (that is, basis states for which the output qubit is |1⟩)."

Isn't this computation also "a sum of exponentially many terms (all the squares of absolute values of the amplitudes)"? So why do we need Feynman Path Integral to show that BQP $\subseteq$ PP?

Comment: It seems that the path integral is to build 'an exponential number of individual polynomial paths to a single destination' so it's in PP. But the 'traditional way'  is to build a highway containing paths to an exponential number of destinations simultaneously (probabilities to all basis by a batch processing), but the highway  is not guaranteed to be built efficiently.

Comment: Or,  if we divide the computation process into N steps (a curve consisted of N segments), then for the path integral way, each segment includes an exponential number of paths but each path is polynomial.  For the traditional way, there is only 1 path, but the number of N to achieve it can not be ensured to be polynomial. Not sure if I understand it right.

Comment: How would you even store these exponentially big matrices?